# How to change the installation location of the Hololens apps (LocalAppData) to an external USB drive?

Tags: uwp, window, hololens

Is it possible to install (deploy) Hololens 2 applications directly to an external hard drive (USB-C)? I'm using Visual Studio as a development/deployment tool.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is not any support to deploy to an external USB drive and they most go to the device main storage when deploying to the actual device.

Besides, you can submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices. If it's a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).